# regex to match everything except protocol from url

Tags: regex, ruby-1.8.7

I have the following regex pattern:
`(?:http.?:\/\/)`

This matches the protocol component from a web url, I want a regex to do the opposit, to match everything except the protocol, so far my every attempt has not worked at all.

Becuase ultimatly what I want to do is check if two urls are the same reguardless of protocol, so I can do:

```
if url_1[regex] == url_2[regex]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/.*?\/\/(.*)/
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a capture group? `(?!.*\/\/).*` almost works, but it still matchs the last `/`, ok, doing this: `(?!.*\/\/)\w.*` works, problem soved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to always capture the part after optional `http://` or `https://` at the start:

```
/^(?:[^:]+:\/\/)?(.+)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS4sJ4/4)

Answer (score 0):

Use this and take the second group **$2**

```
/^(?:[^:]*:\/\/)?(.*?)$/
```